# How do I find a files directory?

Tags: shell, ls, recursive

I am looking for a specific file in OS/X.

I can see the file by using:

```
ls -alR | grep "mkmf.*"
```

This shows my that the file exists.

How do I find what directory the file is located.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `find` which is better suited for your intended purpose:

```
find . -name "mkmf*"
```

It will list all appearances of your pattern including the relative path. For more information look at manual page of find with `man find` or go to http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html

Comment: I advocate -iname instead of -name for case insensitivity

Answer (score -2):

See the manual: `man ls` notes that:

> List  information  about the FILEs (the current directory by default).

So, unless you pass a directory name as an argument, `ls` is showing you the files in your working directory. To see the name of that directory, you can use the `PWD` variable (print working directory):

```
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"
echo "$PWD"
```

Comment: And the downvotes are for what, exactly?